# What are the version numbers of JavaScript and what ECMAScript version do they correspond to?

Tags: javascript

I was looking up the history of JavaScript and found out that the ECMAScript specification is based on it. So JavaScript is older than ECMAScript but seems to have become an implementation of that specification later on.

So what I found out so far is that:

- JavaScript 1.0 was the first version
- ECMAScript 3 is implemented in JavaScript 1.5
- ECMAScript 4 was never completed
- ECMAScript 5 is implemented in JavaScript 1.8.5
- ECMAScript 6 was released 2015 (therefore it is also called ECMAScript 2015)
- ECMAScript 7 was released 2016 (therefore it is also called ECMAScript 2016)

After Version 1.8.5 of JavaScript I can't find any higher version numbers of it. Which versions of JavaScript implement ECMAScript 6 or 7?

Comment: Looks like the current version of JavaScript is only ESCMA 5 Compliant. JavaScript, just like JScript, ActionScript etc,.. implement ECMAScript, therefore, not every new version of ECMAScript has to have a new implementation version of JavaScript implementing it. According to [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history) 1.8.5 implements features for ECMA-262 5th edition - Though each browser can support later features independently of other Browsers.

Comment: It seems that After 1.8.5  all browsers dropped their default scripting engine to comply with ECMA Script.

Comment: You are also improperly mixing the terms ECMAScript and JavaScript. ECMAScript x is not _implemented in_ JavaScript y. JavaScript was first and thus it is the commonly known name for what has become ECMAScript after standardization. However, since then JavaScript is just an obsolete alias for ECMAScript and you can't think of them as the specification on one side and its actual implementation on the other. If you think of implementations you might talk about V8, SunSpider, SpiderMonkey... They may use some version numbers attached to releases that started supporting ES version X or Y some day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history), the JavaScript-specific version numbers were only used by Firefox, and were dropped in Firefox 4.

These days, there's not really such thing as 'the current version of JavaScript' - the ECMAScript standards get created, and the browser vendors implement the features into their JS engines at their own pace. This pace varies wildly - as demonstrated by the very useful [Kangax compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/).

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript#JavaScript_versions:

> **Deprecated**. The explicit versioning and opt-in of language features was Mozilla-specific and [is in process of being removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=867609). Firefox 4 was the last version which referred to an JavaScript version (1.8.5). With new ECMA standards, JavaScript language features are now often mentioned with their initial definition in ECMA-262 Editions such as ECMAScript 2015.

Starting with Firefox 5, changes in JavaScript are listed at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/Firefox_JavaScript_changelog, but not versioned otherwise.

See the lists at [ECMAScript 2015 support in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla) and [ECMAScript Next support in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_Next_support_in_Mozilla) for which features are available in which version of Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

"JavaScript" is a proprietary brand name for an implementation of a scripting language. It was created by Netscape in the early 1990's and, as with all languages, has had revisions over the years. These revisions are tracked with version numbers.  Today, JavaScript is maintained by the Mozilla Organization and they continue to evolve the language and track that evolution via version numbers.

However, many years ago, Netscape wanted "JavaScript" to be recognized as the official scripting language of the web and so they approached the "European Computer Manufacturer's Association" (ECMA) to produce a specification that detailed the "official" language. That language (ECMAScript) has also had revisions over the years and those revisions come with version numbers.

Knowing all this, in casual conversation (and sometimes not so casual), people say "JavaScript" when they actually should be saying "ECMAScript". It's like asking for "Kleenex", when you really just mean tissue.

Today, we don't really worry about JavaScript versions any more. We just worry about runtime environments and what they support.  It is uncommon for new features to be implemented as a whole. Usually, implementations start bringing in new features of ECMAScript bit-by-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Actually they stopped numbering JS version and only using ECMAScript version and ECMAScript year version (like ES6/ECMAScript2015). Now JS is only standardizd by ES. ES6 and ES7 is implemented on ES5 only.